# Objective C: auto play after recording with specific time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation, openal

Good day, can you help me with my project in making a recording project, which is after you recorded it using AVAudioRecorder it will **automatically** play in a certain time can you give me or site me a link regarding with my question..i am badly needed your help masters, because i'm new at iOS development. thanks in advance guys. have a good day.

here's my code @ startrecording:

```
-(void)startRecording:(UIButton *)sender
{   //for recording

    recStopBtn.enabled=NO;
    recStopBtn.hidden = NO;
    recStopBtn.enabled =YES;
    playRecBtn.enabled = NO;
    loading.hidden = NO;
    [loading startAnimating];

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
    if(err)
    {
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
    err = nil;
    if(err)
    {
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }

    recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // We can use kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 (4:1 compression) or kAudioFormatLinearPCM for nocompression
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];

    // We can use 44100, 32000, 24000, 16000 or 12000 depending on sound quality
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];

    // We can use 2(if using additional h/w) or 1 (iPhone only has one microphone)
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // These settings are used if we are using kAudioFormatLinearPCM format
    //[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    //[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    //[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];

    recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MySound.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];



    NSLog(@"recorderFilePath: %@",recorderFilePath);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];

    err = nil;

    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[url path] options: 0 error:&err];
    if(audioData)
    {
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fm removeItemAtPath:[url path] error:&err];
    }

    err = nil;
    recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
    if(!recorder){
        NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: [err localizedDescription]
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        return;
    }

    //prepare to record
    [recorder setDelegate:self];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

    BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
    if (! audioHWAvailable) {
        UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [cantRecordAlert show];

        return;
    }

    // start recording
    [recorder record];

    lblStatusMsg.text = @"Recording...";
    NSLog(@"RECORDING");
    //recIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rec_icon.png"];
    //progressView.progress = 0.0;
    //timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: This question basically asks to write code for you. Too broad. Please read the FAQ, reformulate and get back to us.

Comment: @EricBrotto- sorry for that sir.. i posted my code... here it is..

Comment: If you want help, try telling us what your code does now and what you're trying to get it to do. You'll get the most help if you already have done some work and you just need a tip or some troubleshooting.

Comment: @Dustin the code that i posted here.. is for my startrecording action... and i wanna know how it will automatically playback after some specific time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is how to make something happen after a certain amount of time, use an `NSTimer`. I see you already have one commented out in your code.

To record for a certain amount of time use `recordForDuration`. To stop recording manually use `stop`. To play a recording use the `url` property of the `AVAudioRecorder` in `AVAudioPlayer` method `initWithContentsOfURL`.

So basically, uncomment your `NSTimer` and then do

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
- (void) handleTimer
{
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:nameOfAudioRecorder.url];
}
```